# All matrices of the upper triangular group (or a conjugate of it) have a common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the *special linear group* $SL(2,F_q)$ where $F_q$ is a finite field of order $q$. Is it true that all matrices of the upper triangular group (or a conjugate of it) of $G$ have a common eigenvector?

Comment: What about the first standard basis vector?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "or a conjugate of it".  However, every upper-triangular matrix has the standard basis vector $(1,0,\dots,0)$ as an eigenvector.